# Paginated Drop Down Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown containing 100+ options in it. Can it be paginated so that when user selects the dropdown it shows only 10 options with pager.Is there any angular plugin to do so.Thanks

Comment: Add more details and your findings about this...thanks

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to write some code. This can't be done with the basic '<select>'

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never seen such a widget and i think it's a bit weird to be honest. The user wouldn't expect that behaviour from a dropdown which harm the usability quite a bit.
I would recomment to simply use a normal dropdown instead - if you think of a standard country-dropdown for example (Germany, France, Italy etc.) it holds around 100 entries as well but doesn't do some unexpected behaviour like pagination in it.
The standard select doesn't support this behaviour for sure and i'm not aware of any public widget that does.
So if you really want to do this you will probably have to implement it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, but the pagination should happen a little bit special way. There is a plugin, called `ngInfiniteScroll` which does the pagination based on where additional content for a web page is appended dynamically to the bottom of the page as the user approaches the end of the content.

You may try to use this, but then you have to have your custom dropdown built. In this way you can achieve a convenient usage of a dropdown without showing 100+ hits on start.

ngInfiniteScroll website: https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/